# Tilemaps are loading differently each time

Tags: c++, tilemap, sfml, savegame, file-format

Tilemap data is stored in a 2D array.

It is saved using the following code

```
void Chunk::save_to_file() {
    
    // FILENAME
    std::string filename = std::to_string(chunk_seed);

    std::fstream file;
    file.open(filename + ".chunk", std::ios::out);

    for (int i = 0; i < Constants::BIOMESIZE; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < Constants::BIOMESIZE; j++) {
            file << std::to_string(chunk[i][j]);
            file << ",";
        }
    }

    file.close();
    
}
```

And it is loaded using the following code

```
void Chunk::load_from_file() {
    // FILENAME
    // The chunk will be located at hash(chunk_x, chunk_y) ^ seed = chunk_seed
    std::string filename = std::to_string(chunk_seed);
    // Data within file
    std::string data;

    std::fstream file;
    file.open(filename + ".chunk", std::ios::in);
    file >> data;
    file.close();

    std::vector<std::string> tokens = split(data, ',');
    
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < Constants::BIOMESIZE; i++) {
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < Constants::BIOMESIZE; j++) {
            chunk[i][j] = std::stoi(tokens[i + j * Constants::BIOMESIZE]);
        }
    }
}
```

Tilemaps are *loaded* using the loading function when the program is started up and displayed.

Tilemaps are *saved* using the saving function when the program is exited.

They do not display the same way each time.

I have pinpointed that the problem is in the saving function.

This is because I commented out the saving part and when I was only loading the same files it worked and had the same output each time.

It appears as though the saving function rotates the tilemap by 180 degrees each time I save it.

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rotation comes from the calculation of the index in `load_from_file()`, it should be:

```
chunk[i][j] = std::stoi(tokens[i * Constants::BIOMESIZE + j]);
```

That said, it would be much better if you could save the file in such a way that you can load it back the same way. Instead of using `","` as a separator, use a space (`" "`). Then you can read it in like so:

````
std::ifstream file(filename + ".chunk");

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < Constants::BIOMESIZE; i++)
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < Constants::BIOMESIZE; j++)
        file >> chunks[i][j];
```
````